# Cannot connect to AWS RDS (Postgres) database from db visualizer

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I setup an Amazon AWS RDS database (PostGresql). The endpoint shows:

```
databasekg.cxrchga5vghq.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

The Public Accessibility is Yes.

I get a Connection Error when I try to connect using DBVisualizer. When I try to ping the endpoint, I get Request timed out.

I am using the same Mac to 'ping' that I used to actually set up the AWS RDS database.
What did I miss?

Comment: "Connection Error" is just a class of errors.  What is the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

Check network security group rule, port 5432 needs to open in inbound rules.